# My Link is not Working it was not going to current session it automatically going to home

Tags: javascript, php, html, blogger

whenever the user clicks my shred link they Automatically Redirect to the home page of my site I want they will go to custom URL(current session when URL is created) please help

```js
a = prompt("Please Enter Your Name");
document.write(a);

function sendWhatsapp() {
  var url1 = "www.createwishes.ml/?nam=" + a;
  var sMsg = encodeURIComponent("Special Happy Navratri MSG For You From: " + a + "  Create Your Special Message " + url);
  var whatsapp_url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + sMsg;
  window.location.href = whatsapp_url;
}
```

Comment: You're defining `url1` but are appending `url` to `sMsg`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you need, replace the alert with your redirection.

```js
function sendWhatsapp() {
  var a = prompt("Please Enter Your Name");            
  var url1 = "www.createwishes.ml/?nam=" + a;
  var sMsg = encodeURIComponent( "Special Happy Navratri MSG For You From: " + a + "  Create Your Special Message " + url1 );
  var whatsapp_url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + sMsg;
  console.log(whatsapp_url);
  alert(whatsapp_url);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" onClick="sendWhatsapp()">Click</a>
```